# An arithmetic progression with primes

Tags: mathematics, number-theory

Here is a math puzzle I thought of a while ago:

> Find the longest arithmetic progression that consists only of primes, such that the difference between two consecutive terms is the product of two primes.

Good luck!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The longest such arithmetic progression has length

> $5$

Example

> $5, 11, 17, 23, 29$

Proof

> Let the arithmetic progression be denoted by $a_1, a_2, \ldots$ and consecutive difference be $d = pq$ so that $a_i = (i-1)d + a_1$ and $p$ and $q$ are primes. 
> If $p$ and $q$ are both odd and $a_1$ is odd then $a_2$ is even and greater than $2$, so $a_2$ is not prime.
>  If $a_1 = 2$ and $p$ and $q$ are both odd, then $a_3$ is even and the longest possible prime arithmetic progression has length $2$. 
>  Now let us consider $p=2$ and consider everything modulo $3$. If $q \neq 3$, then $pq \not\equiv 0 (\bmod 3)$ and one of $a_2, a_3, a_4$ is divisible by $3$ so the longest prime arithmetic progression in this instance has length $3$ (example $3, 7, 11$) 
>  Our only other case is $pq = 6$. 
>  Considering everything modulo $5$, we find that one of $a_2, a_3, a_4, a_5, a_6$ must be divisible by $5$ so the longest prime arithmetic progression has length $5$ (this is the case for $a_1 = 5$ so that $a_6$ is the next number divisible by $5$).

Comment: $29 + 2*7 = 43$ all primes? if $p$ & $q$ doesn't have to be the same

Comment: @GintasK we are looking for an "arithmetic progression" so the consecutive differences always have to be the same.

Comment: Oh, right! Sorry, I'm not very observant today :) Friday...

Answer (score 0):

For arithmetic progression being the numbers prime, we can get only three-term in a series at longest. Surely there will include number 3, cause for any three-term arithmetic series, one of the terms must be divided by 3. And as 3 is prime we can include it.
like:

> $3, 5, 7$;
>  $3, 7, 11$;
>  $3, 17, 31$;
>  $3, 23, 43$
>  and so on.

Comment: In the arithmetic sequence $1,4,7,10,\ldots$ none of the terms is divisible by 3.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE. Please read [the tour page](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tour) and [use >! to add spoilers](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/4952/is-there-any-way-we-can-improve-the-spoiler-formatting) to your answer. :)